# Location of Outlook "Send [meeting] response" buttons

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, microsoft-outlook-2016

In an older version of Outlook (desktop client), the Send Response buttons to accept/decline meeting invites were embedded at the top of the Inbox's *Reading Pane* in Outlook 2013.  After the upgrade to 2016, these buttons now appear on the right side of the Outlook window to the right of the *To-Do Bar* and *People Pane*.

Is this a configuration setting that can be changed or is this a design "feature" that will be forced to live with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems this is a "convenience" feature specific to Outlook when using tablets.  Changing the interface in Outlook's quick action menu from "Touch" to "Mouse" moved the action buttons to the reading pane.

Comment: Lifesaver, thanks!

Comment: For those unfamiliar with the quick action menu, where would we find that to make this change? I right-clicked the meeting invite, but I don't see any option to change from "touch" to "mouse"

Comment: Update: found out that it's the very top toolbar (above file, home, etc.). You will need to customize the toolbar with the dropdown to show the mouse/touch mode

Comment: Looking back at this question and answer, I wish I had provided images. I think I tried to be descriptive (image-free) as I was on a work computer and did not feel comfortable dealing with an inquisition. Glad you were able to find it. A feature that Microsoft removed was the ability to delete/archive on new mail pop-up notifications. I don't know if they ever added it back, but it was handy way to deal with junk mail as it popped up.